# SCCM deployment of Office 2019 Standard (KMS activation)

Tags: microsoft-office, sccm

I have been looking everywhere for an answer to this and so far all searches have come up short with irrelevant information for this scenario.

I need to deploy Office 2019 Standard through SCCM into an environment with no internet access. I have read this cannot be done post-2010, but we already have builds that defy this information for Office 2013.

I have made a build using ODT and it fails during install, presumably because although it predownloads 2.6 Gb or so of data, it still needs the internet during the install for god-only-knows why.

I also have the full ISO for 2019 Standard, have extracted it and followed the instructions to run the "Office Customization Tool" by running setup.exe /Admin

This just installs Office, so that too is useless.

Does anyone know how I can actually deploy this in my environment? There must be a way.

Comment: Why do you say that installing Office is useless, or what do you mean by deploy? Have you done all the steps described in [SCCM Office 2019 Deployment](https://systemcenterdudes.com/sccm-office-2019-deployment/)?

Comment: I did not say that office was useless, as such.  I specifically said that "setup.exe /admin" does not launch the customization tool as it is supposed to, it instead just goes ahead and installs office.  In this sense, that command is useless.  It has ONE job and it doesn't even do that job :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether you have added the "[source path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office-deployment-tool-configuration-options#sourcepath-attribute-part-of-add-element)" attribute in configuration file (.xml). This attribute defines the location (Such as a shard folder) of the Office installation files both for download mode and configure mode of ODT.

To deploy Office 2019 from a local source, you need to run ODT to download the instalation content first. There would be an Office folder created automatically.

Then you may install Office 2019 on clients using the installation content which is specified on configuration file.